# Is there a convenient way to pass state from child to child component after a put request or do I have to start using Redux in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**There is no state in the App.js.**

There is a Navbar `(Navbar.jsx)` with local state where the logged in user's name is displayed with `profile()`:

```
{token && <p>Hello {this.state.name}!</p>}
```

*(The `profile()` function is an axios `get` request where I fetch the user's name from the database, then set the state with `setState`.)*

There is a profile page `(Profile.jsx)` with local state where I can update the profile:

```
update = async (e) => {
           await axios
              .put("http://localhost:5000/updateProfile", { name: this.state.name})
              .then((res) =>
                 this.setState({
                     name: this.state.name
                 })
              );
        
};
```

When I update the profile's name in Profile.jsx, in the Navbar the name doesn't change immediately, only after manually refreshing (which never happens). I want it to refresh automatically.

So I put `componentDidUpdate` in the `Navbar.jsx` file but it creates an infinite loop with this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (prevState !== this.state.name) {
        this.profile();
    }
}
```

And if I write this...

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (prevState.name !== this.state.name) {
        this.profile();
    }
}
```

...then the name in the Navbar will still not change immediately because I change this.state.name in the `Profile.jsx` first with the `put` request. And the Profile's state is not connected with the Navbar's state.

Is there a convenient way to pass this new `this.state.name` from `Profile.jsx` to `Navbar.jsx` immediately after the `put` request in `Profile.jsx` is fired?

If I don't use `componentDidUpdate`, then I have to manually refresh the page to see the new name in the Navbar, which almost never happens, since this is a single-page-application.

I guess Redux should be implemented in this case but I just want to try without that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many solutions for make two components or more to communicate with each others let's talk about them.

- the first solution is make the request on the parent component and save it in state of parent for example `App.js` file and passes the specific state as props on the children components.
- the second solution if you using hooks rather than class based component you can use context API as your general state which every component in your app can access to the state and any mutating to the state it will reflect in the whole app.
- the third solution and I prefer not to use it if your application is a small is using an external library like `Redux` or `MobX`which you can make a store and every component can access to it.
  I hope my solution might help you

Answer (score 1):

In such case, react offer a great solution called `React context`. It allow to pass down props or state in component tree.

You can read the official documentation here : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks for your idea! So with Context, I will be able to pass and change state from one component to another one?

Comment: Yes, each component which listening a react context will be updated (re-render) when a props inside context change.

Comment: I will try to implement this then.